# Multithreaded Gstreamer w/ PyGTK crashing (xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost)

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk, pygtk, gstreamer

I understand that one is not supposed to update the UI from other threads in `gtk`, or face consequences, but I am not sure how I can avoid that while using `gstreamer`.

My application crashes from time to time during video stream initialization with a following complaint:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
```

In my code I have added `gtk.thread_init()` call right in the beginning of the GUI class:

```
import pygtk, gtk, gobject
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
```

(I have also tried `gobject.threads_init()`, but this doesnt seem any different). In a separate class, which is run in a separate thread, I start a gstreamer stream to a `tcpserversink` (this gstreamer thread is already a third thread, if someone is keeping count). And then another thread receives this data before pushing the data to `xvimagesink` in the end.

The `xvimagesink` needs a viewport, and I believe this gstreamer callback function is where sometimes gtk goes crazy, when I assign it:

```
def on_sync_message(self, bus, message):
...
if message_name == "prepare-xwindow-id":

  # Assign the viewport
  imagesink = message.src
  imagesink.set_property("force-aspect-ratio", True)
  imagesink.set_xwindow_id(self.window_handle.window.xid)
```

The `self.window_handle` is a pointer to `self.movie_window = gtk.DrawingArea()`, assigned during GUI initialization.

**TL;DR** Is there a safe way of using gtk with gstreamer, since I cannot avoid threading when calling `gst.Pipeline("name").set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)` and view will be a GTK drawing area ?

Comment: I actually got this exact xcb error and "Aborted (core dumped)", with a webkit view with an HTML5 video playing. Oddly enough it happened at or near the video end, so my guess it it may be something with python or GTK itself? I'm not adding special handling of html5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is the fact that you are accessing unprotected Xlib/xcb from 2 threads - once impicitly from your Gtk+ UI and once in the thread where your gstreamer backend callback is executed - which by default is the mainloop you told gstreamer to use (or the thread default mainloop).

---

`gtk.gdk.threads_init()` is already called once the type system is initialized (if I recall correctly, correct me if I am wrong).

---

Use `g_idle_add` (or use `GSource` with a higher priority) (which are threadsafe) with a callback which schedules UI changes in the Gtk mainloop (run by `gtk_main()`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But, hmm, I'm not completely sure how I can use g_idle_add properly in this context. Can I just wrap `imagesink.set_xwindow_id( self.window_handle.window.xid)` to `gobject.idle_add(imagesink.set_xwindow_id, self.window_handle.window.xid)` ?

Comment: I am not exactly sure how the py->C->py magic is done, but I'd give it a shot.