# Updating matplotlib plot in tkinter gui via another process

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, zeromq, python-multiprocessing

I have an interface that I am writing using tkinter. Inside that interface, I have a matplotlib plot. In the background, I have zmq connecting to a server to get data. I am using python's multiprocessing module with a Queue sharing data and a Process running for all of the zmq communication.

In the GUI, I can set up a button to update the plot with the following function:

```
def addData(self):
    if not self.data.empty():
        print "Have Data!"
        self.hist.addQueue(self.data)
        self.hist.updatePlot()
    else:
        print "No Data"
```

However, if I try to create another process that basically puts this inside of a `while True`, I get the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RENDER)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RenderFreePicture)
  Picture id in failed request: 0x160000a
  Serial number of failed request:  2686
  Current serial number in output stream:  2690
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
fish: Job 1, “python clientGUI.py ” terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

I can't find anything about this error that seems to be related to anything that I'm doing.

I can provide other parts of my code if needed, but there's a good bit of code that I didn't want to floood the question with.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with any of this, but there seems to be some relevant information in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626989/multithreaded-gstreamer-w-pygtk-crashing-xcb-xlib-threads-sequence-lost) SO question, it's the same `xcb` error and may be a similar cause.

Answer (score 1):

> Excuse me for not following your post-mortem trails

---

### STEP 0: (re)-align the concept of components

***motto:*** while debugging a mis-directed architecture is possible, the resulting efficiency is rather low compared to a better and a more straightforward design

> **Component Inventory:**

**`Tkinter`** is a very smart framework that works around **`.mainloop()`** ( a central scheduler ) and allows for a soft-real-time scheduling of additional tasks / incl. a planned/scheduled querying of a pool of messaging agents.

**`Queue`** is a mediator-service that on one endpoint receives any message(s) and delivers (**all** of such messages ) to the opposite endpoint. Due to the unmanaged context-less delivery of all messages to the receiving point, the Queue-based automation is not feasible for the GUI-refresh functionality agent in a distributed system with soft-scheduling. ( ref. remarks below on a state-full-GraphModelAGENT, that is better equipped for the task of co-integration with **`Tkinter.mainloop()`**

**`Process`** allow to run separate sub-processes and distribute roles not only via Tkinter tasks ( called in pre-scribed time slots via time-triggered `.mainloop()` and/or event-triggered callback(s) ) but also to run a fully self-contained **`<<_aStateFullGraphAGENT_>>`**, that will have two responsibilities:

**[a]** communicate with Tkinter to update in-sync with Tkinter's **`SIGRTU_aRequestToUpdate`**

+

**[b]** communicate with "server" to update AGENT's internal GUI-ModelPART ( without any push thereof to any third-party, the less to (over)load the GUI-VisualPART via a `FIFO-Queue` ( GUI-VisualPART does not have to suffer from having to handle and repaint all the "past" states of the GUI-Model, but becomes a lightweight **`Repaint-On-Demand`** process, dealing with just the most recent state of the graph ( already assembled and continuously ( async from Tkinter ... ) maintained in `aStateFullGraphAGENT` )

---

### STEP 1: Solution approach

> -- avoid **`FIFO-Queue`** that has to deliver all "GUI-states", that 've become obsolete
>
> ++ add **`aStateFullGraphAGENT`** to maintain the "recent" GUI-state
>
> ++ use **`ZeroMQ`** intelligent process-to-process messaging layer without any inter-thread blocking

ZeroMQ-associated messaging overhead is in the order of microseconds, which does not adversely impact any **`Repaint-On-Demand`** GUI-related operations, so there is a lot of freedom to arrange the Tkinter refresh-rate, be it the `.mainloop()`-scheduled or event-driven.

**Ref.:** >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/25769600/3666197

---

### STEP 2: Validate / adjust feasibility of GUI-repaint latency / overheads

**Ref.:** Processing times in Item 2 >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/25530099/3666197